# Crossbeam Receiver to BufRead?

Tags: rust

I receive a long string (several gigabytes) as chunks of `[u8]`s in a [Crossbeam channel](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/channel/index.html). I want to break it down to lines. How do I turn these chunks into a `BufRead`?

```rust
fn foo(recv: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) {
    let mut buf_read: dyn std::io::BufRead = WHAT_COMES_HERE(recv); // <----
    for line in buf_read.lines() { 
        // ... 
    }
}
```

I make these chunks on another thread since they are CPU-intensive to make. I could use something else than `Vec<u8>` if it makes more sense.

Comment: Look at [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/io/struct.Cursor.html)

Comment: @Jmb: Thanks. I want to treat all incoming chunks as parts of a single `[u8]` stream. If I understand it well, that's not what Cursors do. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything builtin, but it shouldn't be too difficult to write yourself. For example something like this:

```
use crossbeam_channel; // 0.5.4
use std::cmp::min;
use std::io::BufRead;

struct CrossbeamReader {
    recv: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<Vec<u8>>,
    offset: usize,
    buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl CrossbeamReader {
    fn new (recv: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) -> Self
    {
        CrossbeamReader { recv, offset: 0, buffer: vec![], }
    }
}

impl std::io::Read for CrossbeamReader {
    fn read (&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize>
    {
        while self.offset >= self.buffer.len() {
            self.buffer = match self.recv.recv() {
                Ok (v) => v,
                Err (_) => return Ok (0),   // TODO: error handling
            };
            self.offset = 0;
        }
        let size = min (buf.len(), self.buffer.len() - self.offset);
        buf[..size].copy_from_slice (&self.buffer[self.offset .. self.offset + size]);
        self.offset += size;
        Ok (size)
    }
}

pub fn foo(recv: crossbeam_channel::Receiver<Vec<u8>>) {
    let buf_read = std::io::BufReader::new (CrossbeamReader::new (recv));
    for _line in buf_read.lines() { 
        // ... 
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b4901e2c65a1ef4b331560839ac95e4c)